# JSONP callback not working- Even function is global

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I want to call an API deplyed on cross domain. Here is what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pm_url = 'http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/login';
    pm_url += '?u=${args.user}&pw=${args.pass}&format=json';
    $.ajax({
        url: pm_url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'redirect'
    });
});

var redirect=function(data) {
        var token= JSON.parse(data);

        alert(token.data.ticket);
        var entity="";
        var id="";
        var rows="";
        var sortColumn="";
        var sortType="";
        var sAuthor="";
        var permission="";
        var branch="";
        var category="";
        var subCategory="";
        var jurisdiction="";
        var baseDocket="";

        <#if (args.entity) ??>
            entity= "${args.entity}";
        </#if>
        <#if (args.id) ??>
            id= "${args.id}";
        </#if>
        <#if (args.rows) ??>
            rows= "${args.rows}";
        </#if>
        <#if (args.sortColumn) ??>
            sortColumn= "${args.sortColumn}";
        </#if>
        <#if (args.sortType) ??>
            sortType= "${args.sortType}";
        </#if>
        <#if (args.sAuthor) ??>
            sAuthor= "${args.sAuthor}";
        </#if>
        <#if (args.permission) ??>
            permission= "${args.permission}";
        </#if>
        <#if (args.branch) ??>
            branch= "${args.branch}";
        </#if>
        <#if (args.category) ??>
            category= "${args.category}";
        </#if>
        <#if (args.subCategory) ??>
            subCategory= "${args.subCategory}";
        </#if>
        <#if (args.jurisdiction) ??>
            jurisdiction= "${args.jurisdiction}";
        </#if>
        <#if (args.baseDocket) ??>
            entity= "${args.baseDocket}";
        </#if>

        var url="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/documentManagement?entity="+entity+"&id="+id+"&rows="+rows+"&sortColumn="+sortColumn+"&sortType="+sortType+"&sAuthor="+sAuthor+"&permission="+permission+"&branch="+branch+"&category="+category+"&subCategory="+subCategory+"&jurisdiction="+jurisdiction+"&baseDocket="+baseDocket+"&alf_ticket="+token.data.ticket;

        window.location.replace(url);

};
```

But I get this:
 login?u=admin&pw=admin&format=json&callback=redirect&_=1471932310898:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Where I went wrong? Please rectify me.

Comment: what is `<#if (args.entity) ??>` - it's not javscript/jquery or jsonp

Comment: it's a syntax for FTL format, In my ftl file I am using JS.

Comment: looks like the server doesn't like the `:` in the `_` search parameter - I'm assuming the `_=1471932310898:2` is part of the URL, including the `:`

Comment: have you tried `format=jsonp` instead of `format=json`

Comment: complete URL would be http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/login?u=admin&pw=admin&format=json, " _=1471932310898:2" isn't the part of my url.
But response in json would contain Ticket_xxxxxxx

Comment: Api returns data only in json or xml.

Comment: jquery will add that part, the only bit I'm not sure about is the ':2' at the end

Comment: `Api returns data only in json or xml.` - so, no support for jsonp? then you can't use jsonp if the API doesn't support jsonp

Comment: It's a builtin API, means I couldn't do anything to call it from cross origin using JavaScript?